# How can I describe "vertical ellipsis" in testrigor testcase?

Tags: special-characters, automation-testing, testrigor, missing-symbols

How can I describe "vertical ellipsis" in Testrigor testcase?
[the Vertical ellipsis inside red box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFhyX.png)

I tried to describe by 3 dots vertical or vertical ellipsis but didn't work. The testcase is stuck. I searched document in Language Document but cannot find anything
I couldn't continue to do my test

Answer (score 0):

To inspect the element, check if there is a class or label associated with it. Using that information, you can then identify and call the icon.

Additionally, you can utilize the testRigor Chrome extension to record steps, which might make it easier for you to locate and understand the element.